# Schemes as closed subschemes in étale schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes

[The Nagata compactification theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata's_compactification_theorem) asserts that every scheme, separated and of finite type over a Noetherian base scheme $S$, admits an open immersion into a proper $S$-scheme.

It would be useful for me if (what I think of as somehow the dual holds, that is if) every scheme, unramified and of finite presentation over a reasonable base $S$, admits a closed immersion into an étale $S$-scheme.

> Is such a statement known to be true, false, or open?

Well, it is trivially true when $S$ is a field, I wonder if things change when $S$ is taken to be an arbitrary Noetherian scheme.

> Does the statement hold without assuming unramification, if we only ask for a closed immersion into a smooth $S$-scheme?

PS Apologies if this is widely known for algebraic geometers, I am not one, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what is classically known:

**Theorem 1** [[EGAIV$_4$](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1967__32__5_0), Cor. 18.4.7]**.** *Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes, and let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a morphism locally of finite type. Then, for every point $x\in X$, the following are equivalent:*

1. *$f$ is formally unramified at $x$;*
2. *There exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that there is a diagram*
   $$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
     U @>j>> X'\\
     @ViVV @VVhV\\
     X @>f>> Y
   \end{CD}$$
   *where $j$ is a closed embedding and $h$ is étale.*

This says that what you ask for is *locally* true.

Recently, on the other hand, Rydh showed the following, which gives a (sort of) "global" version of the property above:

**Theorem 2** [[Rydh](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00209-010-0691-8), Thm. 1.2]**.** *Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes, and let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a formally unramified morphism that is locally of finite type. Then, there exists a canonical* algebraic space $E_{X/Y}$ *such that there exists a commutative diagram*
$$\begin{CD}
  X @>i>> E_{X/Y}\\
  @| @VVeV\\
  X @>f>> Y
\end{CD}$$
*where $i$ is a closed immersion and $e$ is étale.*

Moreover, Rydh shows that $E_{X/Y}$ is not necessarily a scheme [[Rydh](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00209-010-0691-8), Ex. 2.5], but will be a scheme in the case that $f$ is a local immersion [[Rydh](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00209-010-0691-8), Rem. 1.3]. I don't know if there could exist a scheme that could be chosen instead to give the factorization in Theorem 2.

Comment: Nice answer, what is a algebraic space ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus An algebraic space is a more general version of a scheme, that occurs when you try to take the quotient of a scheme by some equivalence relation. More precisely, for the exact notion used by Rydh, see \[[Rydh](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00209-010-0691-8), App. A\] and \[[Raynaud–Gruson](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01390094), Def. 5.7.1\].

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! Is there similar statements for factorisations as a closed immersions followed by smooth morphisms, without assuming unramification?

Comment: @user337830 For that statement, there exist counterexamples even when $S = \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{C}$: see [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/201).